# Execution order in Prolog: ; operator

Tags: prolog, operators

I am currently delving into Prolog but coming from a JavaScript background a lot seems strange. For instance, I have a definition such as this:

```
np # Subject,
pp # IObject ; np # IObject,
```

However, in executing the result is not as expected. But when using parantheses it is.

```
np # Subject,
(pp # IObject ; np # IObject),
```

This seems strange to me, because `,` is a seperator so parantheses wouldn't be necessary. What is it exactly that parantheses do in Prolog. Please keep in mind that I am very new to Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`,` has a lower [precedence value](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators) than `;`. What this means in Prolog, is that an expression like

```
X ; Y , Z
```

is interpreted as

```
X ; (Y , Z)
```

To group them the other way around, you have to use parenthesis:

```
(X ; Y) , Z
```

Comment: Isn't that very odd, considering that `,` simply is a seperator for a list, whereas `;` is an actual operator?

Comment: The comma is also an operator. Try the query `current_op(Priority, Type, ',').`

Comment: @repeat, yes, it does.

Comment: @repeat indeed, it is.